# GPS patch antenna pcb design

Tags: pcb, rf, antenna, layout, gps

could you please review my layout?

It's the top side where the antenna is actually placed.
[image: top side]

It's bottom side, here I've placed a matching network, LNA (U5)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzDi3.png) and SAW (FL1). The length of the trace between the antenna's output and  IC input is about 15mm (without capacitors and LNA/Filter's size).

I used kicad's calculator to get trace width - 1mm (coplanar trace, dielectric height - 1.6). Both sides of the board are covered with a ground polygon.

[image: bottom side]

It's a recommended layout from the antenna's datasheet. But I've used the matching network from the  LNA's datasheet.

[[image]]

Here is schematic
[image]

Comment: Where's the ground plane flood?

Comment: Generally speaking you have a problem with the following :

Comment: 1. You've got some "long" traces for your LNA VCC etc that you should be able to reduce. If you're PCB is only two layer you may want to consider going to 4 layers with a layer-2 dedicated ground plane. The other inner layer could be a power plane that you can use to deliver the power supply to the semiconductors with vias.

Comment: 2. Your ground planes on top an bottom are missing and should have been added for clarity, but if one assumes they are there, it seem the via stitching is too close to the transmission line and should be furthered out for the micro-strip line

Comment: Linx offers some general advice that you may easily obtain from them directly. You can send an email to Linx and they will offer some advice that will be more specific to their antennas etc.

Comment: Thanks! Do you recommend to move LNA and SAW closer to an input pin? How close the via fence should be to the trace line?

Comment: It really depends how may layers you have to work with. Yes you could move the LNA and SAW closer but it may not be enough as you have some of those other long traces close to the LNA etc. For micro-strip line, if you go to 4 layers anyway, its width will reduce as the ground plane will be more like 0.4mm thick (depends on stack-up chosen). Then you can do a bit of a google search and find various articles on this, but it depends on micro-strip width ...

Comment: I use 2 layer board (to reduce the final cost). Could I call my trace a microstrip? It's just an ordinary trace with an expanded soldering mask  Which tools could be used to check the prototype board? How could I check that my  design is good enough? :-)